# Jquery combobox и bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, jquery-ui, ui-bootstrap

Создал веб-часть в которой часть работает с bootstrap, а логику для combobox сделал из jquery, все работает, но выпадающий список скрывается полями bootstrap: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, где проблема и где копать, код для combobox jquery добавил:

```js
$.widget("ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        var self = this,
            select = this.element.hide(),
            selected = select.children(":selected"),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
        var input = this.input = $("<input>").insertAfter(select).val(value).autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                    var text = $(this).text();
                    if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) return {
                        label: text.replace(
                        new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };
                }));
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                self._trigger("selected", event, {
                    item: ui.item.option
                });
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                        valid = false;
                    select.children("option").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    
                    if (!valid) {
                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        $(this).val("");
                        select.val("");
                        input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

        input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
        };

        this.button = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "Show All Items").insertAfter(input).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon").click(function() {
            // close if already visible
            if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                input.autocomplete("close");
                return;
            }

            // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
            $(this).blur();

            // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete("search", "");
            input.focus();
        });
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.input.remove();
        this.button.remove();
        this.element.show();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
});

$('combo').combobox();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Поэкспериментируйте с CSS свойством `z-index` выпадающей части комбобокса.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, отпишусь по результатам.

Comment: @P. Fateev спасибо, получилось добавил z-index:9999 и вуаля, пиши ответ официальный сделаю пометку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту проблему можно исправить, если установить для выпадающей части комбобокса с помощью CSS свойство z-index c большим значением, чем у перекрывающих его полей.